# How to read all the data in socket programming (c++)?

Tags: c++, network-programming

I am learning socket programming in C++. I have initialised by buffer value at 10. I have used select() function to monitor the socket. When the client sends data which is greater than my buffer can accommodate, it will read buffer size worth of data and will again go through the all my clients and read the remaining data. How can I read all the data at once without parsing through the loop again to read the remaining data ?

Thank you for your help.

```
        for(i = 0;i < max_clients; i++){
        sd = clients_list[i];
        if(FD_ISSET(sd,&temp)){

            char buf[10];
            int n = recv(sd, buf, sizeof(buf),0);
            if(n == -1){
                perror("recv");
            }else if(n == 0){

                cout << "Client is GONE " << endl;
                close(sd);
                clients_list[i] = 0;
            }
            else{

                buf[n] = '\0';
                cout << "From the node: " << buf << endl;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, can't understand your question. It is normal procedure to loop all clients and read all buffers until all data is transferred. You may upsize your buffers to get more data per blocks but still loop. Maybe if this doesn't answer your question - please update your question to be more precise.

Comment: hi. If I have more than 10 bytes of data to be read, it will read those 10 bytes, print it out and go back and parse through the for loop i.e. through all the FD_SET and will again check for some I/O and will print remaining data. Is there a way where I can read all the data at once without going through the for loop again and again and check for some I/O for that socket. I hope this clears out the question. @TomFreudenberg

Comment: @thevortex_17 `recv()` is not guaranteed to receive all bytes requested in one go, so you need a loop regardless. The sender can send the buffer size before sending the buffer content, then the receiver will know how many bytes to expect, and it can then keep reading until that many bytes actually arrive, no matter how many `recv()` calls it takes.

Comment: @thevortex_17 maybe you may change just the loops. Instead looping all clients and ONLY read ONE block you may remain and loop UNTIL NO DATA for the CURRENT client is available anymore. Is that what you like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to complete my comment - this code snippet may help to understand

**not tested code**

```
for (i = 0;i < max_clients; i++) {
    sd = clients_list[i];
    if (FD_ISSET(sd,&temp)) {

        char buf[10];
        int n;
        int flag;

        do {
          n = recv(sd, buf, sizeof(buf),0);
          if (n > 0) {
            buf[n] = '\0';
            cout << "From the node: " << buf << endl;
            ioctl(sd, FIONREAD, &flag);
          } else {
            flag = 0;
          }
        } while (flag > 0);

        if (n < 0) {
          perror("recv");
          // in case of an error you may actively close the socket
          // and end transmission by server
          close(sd);
          clients_list[i] = 0;
        } else {
          cout << "Client has currently no further transmission " << endl;
          // don't close socket maybe later new transmission
          // active close socket by server process only if
          // e.g. a timeout has reached 
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Great, maybe you check this also as your preferred answer to signal "Solved" here. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

By my knowledge you can't determine the buffer size that was sent by the other side. I think your way is the best way to deal with it, but you always can use some tricks.
1. Determine the buffer size that will be sent as a constant and thus you may get the wanted amount every time.
2. A way which I think is the best: Use a self made protocol to determine the length of the message that was sent. You may for example read the 4 first bytes to determine the size of your message and then read the data off the buffer by the given size.

You can use the next transformation:

```
char* c = new char[4];
recv(sd, c, sizeof(c), 0);
int len = (*(int*)c);
delete[] c;
char* but = new char[len];
recv(sd, but, len, 0);
```

Comment: `char* c = new char[4];` could be replaced with `char c[4];` without any loss of functionality, I think.

Comment: You're right, but it doesn't matter if you don't forget to release the memory.

Comment: It still requires two heap accesses more than placing the bytes on the stack; plus even if you never forget to release the memory, the next person to come along and modify the code might not be so astute.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the network is unreliable and unpredictable, so we can not know how many bytes we will receive, that is the start point of designing a server.

Secondly, I think if you want a more elegent server, you may want to try epoll or IOCP, they still have loops, but the I/O multiplexing performance are much better.

Thirdly, if you want to accept all the data, you may try to construct a buffer. In real network, we always buffer the data using kafka or some other apps.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I read all the data at once without parsing through the loop
>   again to read the remaining data ?

Generally speaking, you can't, since all of the data might not be available yet.  If you want, you can tell `recv()` to block until `sizeof(buf)` bytes are available, by passing in `MSG_WAITALL` instead of `0` to its final ("flags") argument... but note that even then it is possible for `recv()` to return fewer than `sizeof(buf)` bytes in some cases (e.g. if a signal is caught, or the connection is closed before `sizeof(buf)` bytes are received, and so on).  So even if you use `MSG_WAITALL` you will still want to implement short-read-handling logic in order to get 100% correct behavior.

Also note that the sender is under no obligation to send all of the bytes you are expecting in a timely manner, nor is the network under any obligation to deliver all of the bytes in a timely manner.  So it's perfectly possible that a sender might send `sizeof(buf)-1` bytes to you, then wait 15 minutes before sending the last byte, and if you are blocked in a `recv()` call waiting for that last byte, then your server will be unresponsive to all of its other clients during that long period.

Therefore when implementing a multiplexed/single-threaded server like this, it's usually best to set the sockets to non-blocking mode, and keep a separate received-data buffer for each client's socket.  That way you can loop through your sockets list, `recv()` as much data as you can from each socket (without blocking), and append that data to that socket's associated buffer, then check the buffer to see if you have enough data in it yet to handle the next chunk, and if you do, handle the chunk and then remove the data from the buffer, and continue.  That way client B never has to wait for client A to finish sending a message to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I have used ioctl() function with FIONREAD to check whether there is more data to read it or not and it has been working.

Here is the code:

```
for(i = 0;i < max_clients; i++){
        sd = clients_list[i];

        if(FD_ISSET(sd,&temp)){
            receive_more:
                char buf[10];
                int arg = 0;
                int n = recv(sd, buf, sizeof(buf),0);

                if(n == -1){
                    perror("recv");
                }else if(n == 0){

                    cout << "Client is GONE " << endl;
                    close(sd);
                    clients_list[i] = 0;
                }
                else{

                    buf[n] = '\0';
                    cout << "From the node: " << buf << endl;
                    ioctl(sd,FIONREAD,&arg);
                    if(arg > 0){
                        goto receive_more;
                    }
                }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @thevortex_17 don't use GOTO its not suggested. Checkout my updated answer. The DO WHILE loop was updated with your ioctl() call.